# Error When Building a Function to Run a Regression n times that Finds B Coefficients

Tags: r, statistics

The problem is asking me to do the following:

"Generate an i.i.d. sample of size n = 100 of the following variables: *y ~ N(0,1)*, *x(subscript k) ~ i.i.d. N(0,1)*, k = 1,..., K where K = 100. For each k = 1,..., K, regress y on a constant and x(sub k)."

I am trying to print the matrix that contains the coefficients for each sample.

Here's my code:

```
    set.seed(1)
    n = 100
    B = 100 
    xk = rnorm(n) 
    y = rnorm(n)

    getbetas = function(n){
      beta = numeric(B)

      for(i in 1:B){
        ols = lm(y~xk[,i])
        beta[k] = ols$coefficients[2]
      }
      return(beta)
    }
    betas = getbetas(n)
```

The error is regarding the ols = lm(y~xk[,i]) line. It says the following:

> Error in xk[,i]: incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: `xk` is a vector of length 100. What are you expecting `xk[,i]` to be?

Comment: You need to generate 100 of those x's (not one) and store them in a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```r
set.seed(2020) 
n <- 100
K <- 100
y <- rnorm(n)
xk <- replicate(K, rnorm(n), simplify = FALSE)

do.call(rbind, lapply(xk, function(x) coef(lm(y ~ x))))
#     (Intercept)            x
#[1,]  0.10522661 -0.031692313
#[2,]  0.11563455  0.048338315
#[3,]  0.10901209 -0.016424163
#[4,]  0.11572731  0.051020006
#[5,]  0.10620789 -0.198357072
#[6,]  0.10584156 -0.040393914
#[7,]  0.12157595 -0.089434432
#[8,]  0.11798138 -0.165129504
#[9,]  0.09731555 -0.113821805
#[10,]  0.11032089 -0.048752670
```

Explanation: `replicate(K, rnorm(n), simplify = FALSE)` creates a list with `K` elements, each of which contains 100 samples from `N(0, 1)`. We loop through these `xk` elements with `lapply`, fit a model `lm(y ~ x)` and extract the coefficients. `do.call(rbind, ...)` then row-binds these coefficients into `matrix`.

---

Alternatively: We note that drawing `K` times a sample of size `N` from `N(0, 1)` is the same as drawing a single sample of size `N*K`. So the above can be written as

```r
xk <- matrix(rnorm(n * K), nrow = n, ncol = K)
t(apply(xk, 2, function(x) coef(lm(y ~ x))))
```

In terms of performance, I imagine the second option being slightly faster.